Is such a property for conditional expectation true?
If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables defined on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$. Is it true that:For $\mathbb{P}$-a.s $\omega$, we have
$\mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y=Y(w)]\quad$  which $\ \mathbb{E}[X|Y=a] \stackrel{\triangle}{=} \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X\cdot 1_{\{|Y-a|<\epsilon\}}]}{\mathbb{P}[|Y-a|<\epsilon]}$
If $Y$ is discrete, we can divide $\sigma (Y)$ into different atoms such as $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and we have
$\mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{Y_i}]}{\mathbb{P}(Y_i)}1_{Y_i}(\omega) $ . So the proposition above is evidently true for discrete random variable $Y$.
But how about a general random variable $Y$?
My thought and confusion:
By Radon-Nikodym theorem, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is defined as a unique random variable(in the means of a.e.) satisfies:$$\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|Y](\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)=\int_A X(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)\quad \forall A \in \sigma(Y)$$
However, such a definition is related on a positive measurable set $A$, I don't know how can I use this definition to a single element $\omega$ in $\Omega$.
Could someone give me a hint about this?

"$\operatorname E[X|\mathcal F]$" is just a notation. In general, the coniditonal expectation is the random variable $Z=:\operatorname E[X|\mathcal F]$ that satisfies $\operatorname E[\operatorname E[X|\mathcal F]\mathsf 1_A] = \mathsf E[X]$ for all $A\in\mathcal F$. In case $\mathcal F = \sigma(Y)$, we write $\operatorname E[X|Y]$ instead of $\operatorname E[X|\sigma(Y)]$, and we write $\operatorname EX|Y$ to refer to the event ${\omega\in\Omega : Y(\omega)\in A}$. Some people prefer to write $\operatorname E[X|Y = Y(\omega)]$.

So both expressions mean the same thing. It's just a matter of personal preference (unless you have a specific definition for either of the expressions).

@SydAmerikaner in some textbooks, $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=a]$ is defined as I menstioned above, that is $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=a] \stackrel{\triangle}{=} \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X\cdot 1_{{|Y-a|<\epsilon}}]}{\mathbb{P}[|Y-a|<\epsilon]}$. So I think it is still necessary to prove  $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=Y(\omega)]$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}X|Y$ (the conditional expectation is defined by R-N derivative).

what I want to mean is  that the two thing has two different definitions and why they are equavalent

Nice question! I would advise you to integrate $E[X|Y=a]$ over the $Y$ measurable sets and check if it is the same integral as $X$. If it is, it is the conditional expectation by definition. I guess you do not even need to check for all $Y$ measurable sets, just a generator family, like $[Y < b]$, would be enough.

The limit may not exist. More assumptions are likely needed such as existence and continuity of PDFs at certain points.

Moreover, the limit may yield paradoxical results; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables such that $X \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$. Then
$$ \mu(A) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in A)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\nu(A) = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in A\}}] $$
define finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, it is clear that $\nu \ll \mu$. Hence by the generalized Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(y)
\mathrel{\stackrel{\triangle}=} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\nu(B(y, \varepsilon))}{\mu(B(y, \varepsilon))}
= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \mathbb{E}[X \mid |Y - y| < \varepsilon] $$
converges for $\mu$-a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, for any $\sigma(Y)$-measurable event $B$, we can find a Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $B = \{Y \in A\}$, hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X \mathbf{1}_B]
= \mathbb{E}[X \mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in A\}}]
&= \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{1}_{A}(x) \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(y) \mathbf{1}_{A}(y) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}y) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(Y) \mathbf{1}_A(Y) \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(Y) \mathbf{1}_B \right].
\end{align*}
This shows that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y] = \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(y)
\qquad \text{for $\mu$-a.e. $y$} $$
and
$$ \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y](\omega) = \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\mu}(Y(\omega))
\qquad \text{for $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. $\omega$.} $$

What book does that chapter belong to?

The equality is valid by the following:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}E[X\mid |Y-a|<\epsilon]=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}E[E[X\mid Y] \mid |Y-a|<\epsilon]=E[X\mid Y=a]$$

I do not understand this "continuous function of $y$". I do not know what "$y$" is. $E[X|Y]$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not defined everywhere. And $\Omega$ has no topology. Would you care to elaborate to someone, like me, who is not an expert? :-)

We can understand $E[X|Y]$ as a function of $y$ by the Doob-Dynkin-Lemma.

As a function of "$y$"... so, you mean as a function in $\mathbb{R}$. The OP has his own definition of $E[X|Y=a]$, and he wants to understand why (if at all) his $E[X|Y=a]$ is the same as yours Doob-Dynking-Lemma $E[X|Y=y]$. I know you have answered it... but I am finding it hard to follow, and hard to connect with the original question.

Essentially what OP is asking is whether $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+}E[X\mid |Y-a|<\epsilon]=E[X\mid Y=a].$

Yeah I think I know what you mean. However, I think we don't even require the continuity of $g(\cdot)$. Following your anwser, for $\omega \in \Omega$, denote $Y(\omega)=a$. And by Doob-Dynkin-Lemma, there is a
measurable function $g$ such that $E[X|Y]=g(Y)$. By my definition, I can easily find:$$E[X|y=a]=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{P({|Y-a|}<\epsilon)} \int_{{|Y-a|<\epsilon}} g(Y) \ dP$$
Then we can use Lebesgue differential theorem to find the right hand of the equality is equal to $g(Y(\omega))$,that is $EX|Y$. Is my thought true?

You are right, continuity is not necessary, although the Lebesgue differentiation theorem is proven for the Lebesgue measure, I think it is possible to extend it for arbitrary measures. I edit my answer.
